# using integral table to evaluate exponential function with coefficient in power

Tags: calculus, integration

I am evaluating this integral:

$\int{x^{4}e^{-{\lambda}ax^{2}}}dx$

from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and $\lambda=1$ in the integral table.

The result is given in terms of $a, n$ and $k$.  My question is:

If $a$ is cubed in the result, and I have a value of $\lambda=2$, does that mean the coefficient $\lambda$ is cubed, or does it mean cube $a$ and then multiply by $\lambda$?

$(a\lambda)^{3}$ 
or
$\lambda(a)^{3}$

Comment: is this a definite integral? Question is not clear in other aspects as well.

Comment: @Maesumi:  Thanks, I added some more detail, hopefully my question is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's note $\,c:=\lambda\,a\,$ then $\;\displaystyle f(c):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty {e^{-c\,x^{2}}}dx=\sqrt{\frac {\pi}c}\;$ if $\,c>0\,$
(using the classical [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) $\;\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty {e^{-t^{2}}}dt=\sqrt{\pi}\;$ with $\;t:=\sqrt{c}\,x\,$)

Taking two times the derivative relatively to $c$ under the integral sign gives :

\begin{align}
f''(c)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^4\;{e^{-c\,x^{2}}}dx=\left(\sqrt{\frac {\pi}c}\right)''=\frac 34\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c^5}}
\end{align}

We deduce that your integral is (in the case $\,c=\lambda\,a>0$) :
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{x^{4}\,e^{-{\lambda}\,a\,x^{2}}}dx=\frac 34\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{(\lambda\,a)^5}}$$
Your question is not very clear but since $\lambda$ and $a$ appear only in the product $\,\lambda\,a=c\,$ they will both be found in the result with the same power as $c\,$ that is $-\dfrac 52$.

If this doesn't answer your question let me please know...

Comment: Did you ever see the remark by Kelvin that, "A mathematician is one to whom the Gaussian integral is as obvious as twice two makes four is to you."

Comment: @Andrew: No but I know that Feynman asked this integral to a guy at a conference. After that he asked him how much was $2+2$ ! :-)

Comment: Yes, this answers my question, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome @CuriousGeorge119 !